# Offline Android GIS App development

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-maps

This is somehow a vague question, I would like to ask for any JavaScript Mapping library that is most effective and efficient in terms of mapping capabilities for android.

Me and my co-developer plans to develop it using Cordova.

I read about [OpenScale](http://openscales.org/), we wanted that the app will work in offline with base map (preferably Google tiles or any available tiles that can be downloaded).

The user just need to draw a polygon on the map and using a JS library, perform an "intersect" query and will return an information what feature it intersected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mapping library I would recommend either [Google Maps API Javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). Both are really powerful and will allow you to create entities (points, polylines and polygons). Choosing one over the other can be more a license question: [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/) you can see the pricing and plans for Google Maps API Javascript. OpenLayers is open source (under the [2-clause BSD License](https://tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-2-clause-license-(freebsd))).

To perform spatial operations on JavaScript I would recommend [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) which, according to the documentation:

> JSTS is an ECMAScript 2015 library of spatial predicates and functions for processing geometry conforming to the Simple Features Specification for SQL published by the Open Geospatial Consortium. JSTS is also a port of the well established Java library JTS.

Comment: Thanks, any idea on handling base map? So that app will still run in offline.